# 19.04 -> 19.10 - Frozen at Login Screen / Black Screen (Can boot in via recovery mode)

Tags: nvidia, 19.04, 19.10

EDIT: Reverting back to nouveau and unblacklisting the driver works for me.  However, this is not a fix since i'd like to get to the latest drivers.

Like a few others, i recently decided to jump on the 19.10 train and updated it on my ubuntu 19.04 via software updates.  Everything went fine until my screen went black during the update (since it was updating nvidia drivers) and I forced a reboot.

After which, I was getting a Kernel Panic error so I booted up 5.0.0 in recovery mode and ran `dpkg` to fix up the issues, selected `keep maintainer version` or something like that.  It installed the rest of the update fine and rebooted.  However, I cannot login as the login screen freezes after I type in my password.  I read from other SO post that it's primarily a graphics card issue.  However, I can still boot in fine from `Recovery mode` -> `Resume Normal Boot`

Here is my current graphics card driver:

```
(base) kevin@kevin-desktop:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001380sv00003842sd00003753bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Recovery mode boot shows that it's using the latest driver
[image: driver]

Other things I have tried:

- `nodemodeset` - doesn't work
- `apt update && apt upgrade` - everything is up to date
- `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` - it actually had a few held packages that were broken so i reinstalled them via `sudo apt install` and then everything else went fine.  I still had freezing on regular boot

Comment: [The solution provided by TensorVortex works](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183357/1007861)

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1183357/976775

Notable, you are installing the 435 driver, I found this driver still had issues, I had to go back to the 430 driver specifically to resolve the issue.

I disregarded the "auto-login" step at first, but this is actually a crucial step. It seems to log your account in automatically and when trying to login *again* it gets stuck.

Comment: I have the same issue, i rather suggest the following answer, as it provides a solution while still having the latest drivers: https://askubuntu.com/a/1187732/140762