# Can't log in to Ubuntu 19.10, freezes upon Ctrl+Alt+F3

Tags: boot, graphics, login, i3-wm, 19.10

I recently upgraded to 19.10 from 19.04.

Everything appeared to work correctly, however just last night I did a `apt update`/`apt upgrade` and some kernel updates occurred.

Now when I get to the login screen, I am unable to login. Upon entering the user password and hitting the login button, I am instantly sent back to the select user part of login.

Interestingly, if I use the GUI element to restart the computer, the warning shows that I am already logged in, **even if I had not yet tried to log in after starting the computer.**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> freezes the screen and I am unable to do anything. Although <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> still works to restart the machine.

Selecting the latest kernel recovery boot from the grub menu works fine and I am immediately put into a desktop session (i3) after auto login. Once booted into recovery mode `apt update`/`apt upgrade` and `dpkg --configure -a` report 0 changes.

Any ideas on how to debug/fix this? I have a suspicion that my account is auto logging in, but then I am somehow bumped to the Ubuntu login screen where the strange state is causing issues.

I have a i5-4460 CPU, MS H81M-E34 (MS-7817) Motherboard, and a Geforce GTX 1050Ti graphics card. I am using the nvidia-driver-430 package.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend you **[edit]** this to give the make/model of your machine (or what motherboard it has, if custom-built) and what graphics card it has. If you can also include the output of `sudo lshw -C display`, that may help. From [that comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183299/ubuntu-19-10-cant-login-freezes-upon-ctrlaltf3/1183323#comment1977086_1183323) it sounds like you may be saying you have an Nvidia card, but I am not sure if that's the case or which one. Also, if workarounds have helped--like booting an earlier kernel--you can give details about that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1845801

Valtteri Vainikka (vrln) wrote on 2019-11-08:

> I think Martin on to something concerning GRUB/Linux boot options,
>   more specifically the "splash" one. With testing-updates enabled what
>   currently happens for me:
>
> If I set automatic login on I'm stuck with the standard infinite login
>   loop, but with the distinction that I can now no longer enter another
>   TTY via ctrl+alt+F3 for example to fix it straight away. The whole
>   system now just freezes, so I fixed it via recovery mode.
>
> Out of curiosity I then went and disabled the following line in
>   `/etc/default/grub` and ran `sudo update-grub`:
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
>
> Result: Automatic login now works perfectly, no issues anymore.

Another more radical approach is to disable auto-login.

NOTE: This grub config line keeps reappearing after some system updates that include a grub update, and you have to start again this process.

Comment: it is also possible to enable a login timeout for example of like 3 seconds. just open the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` in your tty session and comment out the automatic login and comment in the timed login, also set the correct username.  but still just a workaround

Comment: This worked for me. However, today's Ubuntu software update broke even this workaround.  So now I have to revert to disabling automatic login...

Comment: Also worked for me however I have a feeling the next update will break this

Answer (score 8):

Same here. I've ended up removing the Nvidia driver:

```bash
sudo apt remove nvidia-*
```

It's not a full fix but at least I can log in again and get to a desktop.

Comment: Thats good info. I can rollback the kernel until the driver is fixed. At least I know what is broken now!

Answer (score 5):

I have the exact same issue on my desktop. I fixed it like this:

1. Uninstall the nvidia driver.

   I uninstalled cuda with 418 driver from cuda10 directory with uninstall script. and also from cuda10.1 directory. Then I used the script `sudo apt remove nvidia-*` to clean things up.
2. Disable automatic login (even if you never enabled it, it is set to automatic in 19.10 for some reason). You can find this in *System Settings → Detail → Users*.
3. Install the nvidia-435 driver from Additional Drivers.
4. Reboot.

Comment: The nvidia driver page (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) indicates I should use the 430 driver package, and also shows the 435 package as being older. Do you know what the difference between the two packages is?

Comment: @SamCoulter no idea, I was on 430, I thought 435 is newer so I installed that...

Comment: @TensorVortex Your solution (disabling auto login) worked for me! I had this issue ever since upgrading to 19.10 and had to rollback to nouveau on my old GTX750.  Ive since upgraded to 1660 and was forced to use nvidia drivers.  I had the same freeze issue with nvidia-440 installed but disabling auto login worked!  Also for anyone having trouble, booting into recovery mode will allow you to access your linux to make changes