# 19.10 Automatic login doesn't work for me when i'm on a nvidia driver and cannot pass the login screen once i've activated automatic login

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, 19.10

On the X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver automatic login does work, but as soon as i use nvidia 435, 430 or 390 i get stuck with a login screen that wont log me in.

I've had no issues that resembles this on ubuntu 19.04.

It's not that big of deal (having to enter my password i mean), but if there is something i can do to solve this i would love to be in the know.

Update: So i decided to connect the tv directly to the pc the resolution was reset to full hd and now i couldn't enter the desktop even without automatic login disabled. So i entered recovery mode > followed by the resume normal boot procedure and now i could get back in, so i tried automatic login again, and yeah, no go on entering my desktop, so back to recovery mode and the resume normal boot procedure... To my surprise i was treated to an automatic login, but i didn't last, because when i rebooted there was the same problem again.

Thanks for reading.

i7 6700K
MSI master M7 Z170
16GB DDR4

nVidia 1030GT hooked up through hdmi 2.0 on an Onkyo TX-NR646 receiver that leads me to a 4K philips TV. Same issue with a 960GTX by the way.

Resolution: 3840 x 2160 (16:9) @60Hz @200% scale

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't log in to Ubuntu 19.10, freezes upon Ctrl+Alt+F3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183299/cant-log-in-to-ubuntu-19-10-freezes-upon-ctrlaltf3)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your issue is quite familiar to the "Auto Login bug with nvidia drivers enabled" [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1845801). You might want to try some of the suggestions posted there and also post your info on that thread so it can help debug the issue overall. Seems like the only way to go forward for now is to leave auto login disabled if you want to use the nvidia drivers

Comment: Thanks, will do

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's just saved me a morning of head-scratching.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger for this bug is the nvidia modules being built into initrd.img files due to the `splash` option in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`s `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` setting. I was able to get autologin working on 20.04 under the nvidia-340 drivers as follows.

1. Edit `/etc/config/grub` to remove `splash` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
2. Regenerate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with `sudo update-grub`
3. Regenerate the initrd.img files by using `sudo apt-get --reinstall install` to reinstall the currently installed kernel packages.

After rebooting, the autologin feature in gdm3 can be reselected and on the next reboot, it will autologin as expected. Not loading the nvidia module through `initrd.img` also eliminates the hangs on restarting while autologin is enabled.

Comment: Worked for me .. :)