# Automatic login no longer working in 19.10

Tags: 19.10, auto-login

I had an Ubuntu 19.04 with automatic login enabled (desktop PC). After the upgrade to 19.10 I could no longer log in successfully. After booting an unlock screen was displayed where I could select my username, then enter my password and then click "Unlock". However after entering my password and clicking "Unlock" or pressing Enter nothing would happen and I would stay in the unlock screen. Even the shutdown and restart menu actions would work. A count down would be displayed but nothing would happen after it reached 0.

I had to boot with an old kernel (5.0.0-31-generic) to which I could still log in automatically, disable automatic login and then reboot so that I could successfully log in again with the new kernel. Enabling automatic login again causes the issue to appear again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't log in to Ubuntu 19.10, freezes upon Ctrl+Alt+F3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183299/cant-log-in-to-ubuntu-19-10-freezes-upon-ctrlaltf3)

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. I hope it could be found a solution to this.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the above answer, I solved like this:

Edit grub config with `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

locate the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and empty it or at least remove `splash`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

save and run `sudo update-grub`

Edit GDM config with `sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf` and set

```
AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = <your user here!>
```

reboot (`sudo reboot`) and it should login automatically.

Answer (score 4):

It seems your issue is quite familiar to the "Auto Login bug with nvidia drivers enabled" [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1845801). You might want to try some of the suggestions posted there and also post your info on that thread so it can help debug the issue overall. Seems like the only way to go forward for now is to leave auto login disabled.

Comment: I do indeed have the proprietary nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: yes then it definitely looks like that issue around auto login. Does the issue still happen when you disable auto login ?

Comment: No, disabling auto login fixes the issue. Enabling it again and the issue appears again.