# Nvidia drivers wont work on normal boot but works on recovery mode

Tags: nvidia

I've been trying to fix this for days and I know a lot of people have the same issues but no fix worked for me so I'd need some help here.

I've installed an Ubuntu dual boot with the default drivers for my GPU and it works fine but only on one of my two monitors.
I've figured out I needed to switch to NVIDIA proprietary to make it works, but I encounter multiple problems

When I boot on recovery mode everything works fine.
When I boot on normal mode I either get

- directly to desktop but it's frozen (usually when I spend some time trying to edit grub or whatever on startup but end up saving nothing)
- on a logging screen (which I've disabled) which either makes me log in a loop or freeze right as I enter my password.

I may have understood that I have multiple problems at once : the logging screen loop, my new M2 ssd being too fast for my GC...

As I've browsed similar issues I tried few fixes but none of them worked

- `nomodeset` on grub
- few tweaks I dont remember instead of `quiet splash` in grub
- installed every driver provided by `ubuntu-drivers devices` which I've updated
- lots of people said to delay the boot (on lightdm) but that's not what my ubuntu uses and as I'm quite new I couldn't figure out how to do it on mine.
- most thing [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers?newreg=c79cc4ba90fe447f8304eea8e14e48c2) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527356/nvidia-driver-normal-boot-results-in-blank-screen-recovery-boot-works-fine?rq=1)

Here are my specs

- Ubuntu 20.04
- STRIX Z270E GAMING
- GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.2
- NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM98 (samsung evo plus 1To)
- two screen (1 classic that works and the other one in WQHD that doesnt work for nouveau driver)

Feel free to ask me for any clarification (but I could need some help if you ask me the logs of the boot for example)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to disable auto-login.
*Settings > User > unlock > disable auto-login*

thanks [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182720/19-04-19-10-frozen-at-login-screen-black-screen-can-boot-in-via-recovery?rq=1) and thus [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183299/cant-log-in-to-ubuntu-19-10-freezes-upon-ctrlaltf3/1183357#1183357)